# My code will not add to a list and would print anything

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to add all number greater than 10 that is generated by the random int operator to my list (lisps) and have all number less than 10 printed out. Whenever I run it it doesn't give back an output. Can you look it over and see where the problem is.

```
from random import randint

lisps = []

rand = randint(0,20)

while len(lisps) > 5:
    if rand > 10:
        lisps = lisps.append(rand)
        print(f'{rand} Greater than 10')
    elif rand < 10:
        print(rand)
        print(f'{rand} less than 10')


#It doesn't print anything.
```

Answer (score 2):

The loop only executes when lisps contains more than 5 items. But lisps starts off empty, so the loop is never even entered and lisps remains empty.

Perhaps you meant `while len(lisps) < 5:`, so that the loop executes as long as there are *fewer* than 5 items?

Comment: Worth noting: `lisps = lisps.append(rand)` -> `lisps.append(rand)`.

Comment: One more thing: `rand` is working only once, it should be also added in the `while`

Answer (score 1):

Never mind I got it. I saw that I put greater than 5 instead of less than less than 5.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from random import randint

lisps = []


while len(lisps) < 5:
    rand = randint(0,20)
    if rand > 10:
        lisps.append(rand)
        print(lisps)
        print(f'{rand} Greater than 10')
    elif rand < 10:
        print(rand)
        print(f'{rand} less than 10')
```

This will work!

You are also generating a `random int` only once. Put it inside `while` so that different value is appended every time.

The correct way to append to a list is `lisps.append(rand)` not the way you have done.